# Why SSIS logging is not working in a script component / script task when inside Foreach container

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package that has a ForEach container (to loop through multiple files).

Outside the loop I also have a script task where I'm using Dts.Log() function to log some information. It works fine.

Inside the loop I have several tasks such as another script task and dataflow task. I'm using Dts.Log() in another script task as well but it logs nothing. I've checked all logging settings and they seems to be right.

Inside the dataflow I also have one script component where I'm trying to use that Log() function with no success. Once again I've checked my setting and they seem to be correctly set (according to this one [SSIS: Why is this not logging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348476/ssis-why-is-this-not-logging)).

I'm able to log inside the loop by raising events though (FireInformation http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.idtscomponentevents.fireinformation(v=sql.105).aspx)

I remember reading somewhere that there are some restrictions in debugging when inside the foreach container. So is there some sort of things in Logging as well or is this something else?

I can't provide any code samples (at least not right now) so we have to keep the discussion at the certain level.

Comment: 1. Have you tried to tick `Windows Event Log`, to see wherever the events being raised at all?     2. If you already have `Script Task`, you can use your own logger or 3rd party logger, or even use Window Event Logger directly - `EventLog.WriteEntry`